# utf-8 gets stored differently on server side (JAVA)

Tags: encoding, utf-8, byte, decoding, arraybuffer

Im trying to figure out the answer to one of my other questions but anyways maybe this will help me.

When I persist and entity to the server, the byte[] property holds different information than what I persisted. Im persisting in utf-8 to
the server.

An example.

```
{"name":"asd","image":[91,111,98,106,101,99,116,32,65,114,114,97,121,66,117,102,102,101,114,93],"description":"asd"}
```

This is the payload I send to the server.

This is what the server has

```
{"id":2,"name":"asd","description":"asd","image":"W29iamVjdCBBcnJheUJ1ZmZlcl0="}
```

as you can see the image byte array is different.

WHat im trying to do it get the image bytes saved on the server and display them on the front end. But i dont know how to get the original bytes.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are wrong. Both method stored the ASCII string `[object ArrayBuffer]`.

You are confusing the data with its representation. The data it is the same, but on both examples, you represent binary data in two different way:

The first as an array of bytes (decimal representation), on the second a classic for binary data representation: BASE64 (you may discover it because of final character `=`.

So you just have different representation of the same data. But so the data is stored on the same manner.

You may need to specify how to get binary data in string form (as in your example), and so the actual representation.

Comment: do you  know how I could get the array buffer from the base64 with javascript?